# SSO login redirection in Uber Rides Android SDK

Tags: android, uber-api

I've encountered an issue with authentication flow.

1. Uber app is installed on the device
2. Start SSO flow from third party app with REQUEST scope and redirection URL in Uber dashboard "http://localhost"
3. User app show login and registration possibilities
4. User tap on login button
5. And login through G+ account
6. User is redirect to home screen of Uber app

After G+ login user should be redirected to scope confirmation view then to third party app but this is not happening.

Should I add more configuration to Uber SDK/Dashboard ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue. We'll handle it here: https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/issues/36